# Index out of range. Can't get selectedIndexChanged as index for query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, detailsview

I get an 'index out of range error' however do not no why,

I have  gridview master control and am using SelectedIndexChanged to display more information on the selected row in a details view, however when I try to point to the selected row in the query it gives an index out of range error.

I am using a ADO.NET Entity model and want to essentially retrieve data about the selected gridview row using another database table called EventLog and populate the details view with that.

> Error Message (Line 50)
>
> Line 50:         description =
>   Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().EventDesc.ToString();
>
> Line 51:         resultCode =
>   Convert.ToInt32(Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().ResultCode);

Here is my SelectedIndexChanged code:

```
<!-- language: lang-c# -->
string description;
int resultCode;
int TaskInstanceID;
string Eid;
int IntEid;

//added 's' at end of eventDetailsView due to conflicting naming conventions
DetailsView eventDetailsViews = new DetailsView();

public void tasksGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventDetailsView.Visible = true;
    //Get's the currently selected row
    GridViewRow row = tasksGridView.SelectedRow;
    selectedId = row.Cells[1].Text;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(selectedId);

    Eid = tasksGridView.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    IntEid = Convert.ToInt32(Eid);

    description = Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().EventDesc.ToString();
    *///description = Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().EventDesc;*
    resultCode = Convert.ToInt32(Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().ResultCode);
    TaskInstanceID = Convert.ToInt32(Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().TaskInstanceID);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3]
        {
            new DataColumn("Eid", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("TaskInstanceID", typeof(int))
        });
    dt.Rows.Add(Eid, description, TaskInstanceID);

    eventDetailsViews.DataSource = dt;
    eventDetailsView.DataBind();

}
```

Here is my query code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    infordevEntitiesOrbis dbContext = new infordevEntitiesOrbis();
    //Acting as a using SqlConnection to the database
    using (infordevEntitiesOrbis context = new infordevEntitiesOrbis())
    {
        //On pageload, not on user interaction (Occurs regardless)
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            d = d.AddMonths(-3);

            //Query written using LINQ
            Tquery = (from tasks in context.Tasks.AsEnumerable()
                      select new Task()
                      {
                          TaskID = tasks.TaskID,
                          TaskName = tasks.TaskName,
                          TaskPath = tasks.TaskPath,
                          Schedules = tasks.Schedules
                      }).ToList();
```

ASP Code for gridview and details view:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="tasksGridView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="TaskID" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="tasksGridView_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="tasksGridView_SelectedIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="tasksGridView_RowDataBound1" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskID" HeaderText="TaskID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TaskID"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskPath" HeaderText="TaskPath" SortExpression="TaskPath"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TaskName" HeaderText="TaskName" SortExpression="TaskName"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RunTime">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UTCRT" runat="server" Enabled="false" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="UTCLRT" runat="server" Enabled="false" BorderStyle="Dotted" BorderWidth="1px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="True" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black"></FooterStyle>

                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></HeaderStyle>

                <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black"></PagerStyle>

                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#6699FF" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></SelectedRowStyle>

                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7"></SortedAscendingCellStyle>

                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B"></SortedAscendingHeaderStyle>

                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5"></SortedDescendingCellStyle>

                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121"></SortedDescendingHeaderStyle>
            </asp:GridView>


            <asp:DetailsView ID="eventDetailsView" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False">
                <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            </asp:DetailsView>
```

RowDataBound:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in tasksGridView.Rows)
    {
        currentDataIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (utcRnTime != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    utcLRTUpdate = Tquery[currentDataIndex].Schedules.FirstOrDefault().UtcLastRunTime.Value;
                    utcRTUpdate = Tquery[currentDataIndex].Schedules.FirstOrDefault().UtcRunTime.Value;
```

Any help would be appreciated!
I don't think any more code is required.

Comment: However you should provide *where* you get that error.

Comment: Have you checked if your methods has the correct items in it? e.g, when browsing though the cells if the count is greater than the number you are querying?

Comment: You do not check if IntEid = Convert.ToInt32(Eid); is not out of range

Comment: No I havent checked if IntEid is out of range however I know it isnt, for example If I click on row 7 the table has more rows then 7.

Comment: I feel as though it has something to do with .FirstOrDefault()

Comment: If `Tquery` is populated on page load, but not on post back, what is persisting it between post backs?  What is the length of `Tquery` in `tasksGridView_SelectedIndexChange` when stepping through in Debug mode?

Comment: Found a solution to this problem, shared it on this post.

Comment: I have found a solution to this problem and posted it on this answer.

Comment: I declared Equery before Tquery in a separate method which can be called at anytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a separate query for the EventLogs table and using the query results to allocate variables 'description', 'resultCode' and 'TaskInstanceID'.

As you can see the new query is almost identical to the old one:

```
Equery = (from eventLog in context.EventLogs.AsEnumerable()
                  where eventLog.TaskID == IntEid && eventLog.ResultCode != 0 && eventLog.EventType == 2
                  select new EventLog()
                  {
                      TaskID = eventLog.TaskID,
                      EventDesc = eventLog.EventDesc,
                      ResultCode = eventLog.ResultCode,
                      TaskInstanceID = eventLog.TaskInstanceID
                  }).ToList();
```

Then setting the query results here:

```
        description = Equery.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskID == IntEid).EventDesc.ToString();
        resultCode = Equery.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskID == IntEid).ResultCode.ToString();
        TaskInstanceID = Equery.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskID == IntEid).TaskInstanceID.ToString();
```

Comment: However just using Equery to bind to gridview instead of looping and setting variables    description = Equery.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TaskID == IntEid).EventDesc.ToString();

Comment: Alothough I am still unsure why it did not work using Tquery, if anyone knows the particular reason for this please feel free to add an answer!

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you're trying to access an object in the TQuery list on *index* `Eid` which might not exist (if the id is say 13020 it will look at that position in the list). Use `Tquery.First(t => t.TaskID === Eid).EventLogs...` to get the task you're looking for.

Comment: That is still giving me the error after:  description = Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.First(t => t.TaskID == IntEid).EventDesc;

Comment: Ah, I was a bit unclear. First() should be run Tquery. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to look up a task in the list via its ID (I assume `Eid` and `IntEid` are the same as `Task.TaskID`, but it's hard to tell from your code). You can't do that with a list and the `[]` property... that goes by index, not ID.

Perhaps you should use a dictionary instead:

```
Tquery = (
             from tasks in context.Tasks.AsEnumerable()
             select new Task()
             {
                 TaskID = tasks.TaskID,
                 TaskName = tasks.TaskName,
                 TaskPath = tasks.TaskPath,
                 Schedules = tasks.Schedules
             }
         )
         .ToDictionary
         (
             task => task.TaskID //Create a dictionary using the TaskID as the key
         );
```

Then when you do this:

```
description = Tquery[IntEid].EventLogs.FirstOrDefault().EventDesc.ToString();
```

...you will actually be looking up by ID instead of index.

Comment: I am now unable to .dataBind() the gridview, with error message ' does not contain a property with the name 'TaskID'.  **Why is that?**

Comment: IntEid and Eid are the selected row of the gridview control, storing the value as string and int. They are not the Task.TaskID directly however I use these variables to compare the selected row to the taskID. Still having the same problem above when using a dictionary, may have to re-write a few things to allow a dictionary to work in place of the list